# Слово "пусть" - это какая часть речи?

Tags: морфология

Слово "пусть" - это какая часть речи?

Answer (score 12):

Это частица. Образует повелительное наклонение глагола. *Пусть придет.*

Может выступать и в роли подчинительного союза с уступительным значением. *Пусть дождь, а мы все равно пойдем гулять*

Comment: А ещё разг. частица со значением "ладно, хорошо":Пусть , я согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Образует повелительное наклонение глагола и частица "пускай". Её можно спутать с глаголом: "пускай ответит", "пускай мыльные пузыри"